# Text overflow on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to put a text inside de window. However, it is out of pixels and I don't know how to fix it.
This is how it looks now:
[image]

This is part of my code:

```
SizedBox(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
  child:
    Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
     children: [
        Row(children: [
        Text('FRI, 4 MAR · 16:00', style: dateStyle),
      ],),
    Row(children: [
       Text('Chess Competition at Tetuan',
        style: eventStyle, textAlign: TextAlign.left),
    ],),
),
```

I want that if the text (that for the moment is hardcoded) can't be shown in the same line, automatically changes to the other.

Comment: Is multiline title allowed or you want it in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Row widget tries to give infinite width space for all its children so text widget is getting infinite width.
To make text widget render text on next line we need to provide fix width.
To achieve that you can use Expanded widget, it will take all space available such that it fits the constraint of the row.

```
SizedBox(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'FRI, 4 MAR · 16:00',
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Chess Competition at Tetuan',
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, Wrap your Text inside [**`Expanded`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) Widget

```
SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  'FRI, 4 MAR · 16:00',
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  'Chess Competition at Tetuan',
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Result screen-> [image]

Comment: @lauv if its help to you accept and upvote my answer, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Flexible` to resize the widgets in `rows` and `columns`. It's mainly used to adjust the space of the different child widgets while keeping the relation with their `parent widgets`.

Meanwhile, `Expanded` changes the `constraints` sent to the children of `rows` and `columns`; it helps to fill the available spaces there. Therefore, when you `wrap` your child in an `Expanded widget` it fills up the empty spaces.

Providing these videos from the Flutter's Official YouTube channel just to help out people, who might look for this in the upcoming future...

1.[Expanded](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo)

2.[Flexible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CI7x0mAZiY0)

**Example:**

```
 Flexible(
   child: Text()),

 Expanded(
   child: Text()),
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text widget in a **Flexible** widget as follows-

```
SizedBox(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
  child:
    Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
     children: [
        Row(children: [
        Text('FRI, 4 MAR · 16:00', style: dateStyle),
      ],),
    Row(children: [

//Start of flexible widget

       Flexible(
           child:Text('Chess Competition at Tetuan',
        style: eventStyle, textAlign: TextAlign.left),
    ],),),
),
```